# How to iterate through pages of results for web scraper and parse individual page results for extra details?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have the following web scraper built but am wondering how to iterate through pages of results (1) and also parse results from an individual url to add details to my dataset. For example, I'd like to get the description body from the individual listing page as well as vehicle condition for all URLs that pop up in my initial code below (2).

```
URL = 'https://orlando.craigslist.org/search/cto?auto_title_status=1&max_auto_miles=50000&nearbyArea=125&nearbyArea=20&nearbyArea=219&nearbyArea=237&nearbyArea=238&nearbyArea=330&nearbyArea=331&nearbyArea=332&nearbyArea=333&nearbyArea=37&nearbyArea=376&nearbyArea=557&nearbyArea=638&nearbyArea=639&nearbyArea=80&searchNearby=2'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find(class_='rows')
car_elems = results.find_all('li', class_='result-row')

craigs_list = []
# Parse each offer tile
for car_elem in car_elems:
    price_elem = car_elem.find('span', class_='result-price')
    #url_elem = car_elem.find('a', class_="result-image gallery")['href']
    url_elem = car_elem.find("a",{"class":"result-image gallery"})['href']
    title_elem = car_elem.find('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk')
            

    #print(title_elem.text.strip())
    #print(url_elem)
    #print(price_elem.text.strip())
    #print()
    craigs_item = {
        'title': title_elem,
        'price': price_elem,
        'links': url_elem,
        'date': date_elem
    }
    
    craigs_list.append(craigs_item)
    
craigsList_df = pd.DataFrame(craigs_list)
print(craigsList_df)
```

Comment: Can you clarify which part you're struggling with, specifically? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm struggling with iterating through the pages of results and grabbing descriptions from the individual pages - it's a two part question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to scan every ad-listing for individual details:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://orlando.craigslist.org/search/cto?auto_title_status=1&max_auto_miles=50000&nearbyArea=125&nearbyArea=20&nearbyArea=219&nearbyArea=237&nearbyArea=238&nearbyArea=330&nearbyArea=331&nearbyArea=332&nearbyArea=333&nearbyArea=37&nearbyArea=376&nearbyArea=557&nearbyArea=638&nearbyArea=639&nearbyArea=80&searchNearby=2'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, 'html.parser')
car_elems = soup.select('.rows li.result-row')

craigs_list = []
for car_elem in car_elems:
    craigs_item = {
        'title': car_elem.find('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk').text,
        'price': car_elem.find('span', class_='result-price').text,
        'link': car_elem.find("a",{"class":"result-image gallery"})['href']
    }
    
    print(craigs_item['link'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(craigs_item['link']).content, 'html.parser')

    desc = soup.select_one('#postingbody')
    # sometimes, the posting is deleted. If yes, skip it.
    if not desc:
        continue
    desc.select_one('.print-information').extract()
    craigs_item['desc'] = desc.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')

    for a in soup.select('.attrgroup')[-1].select('span'):
        k = a.find(text=True)
        v = k.find_next(text=True)
        if k.strip():
            craigs_item[k.split(':')[0]] = v

    craigs_list.append(craigs_item)
    
craigsList_df = pd.DataFrame(craigs_list)
print(craigsList_df)
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

---

EDIT: To handle pagination:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://orlando.craigslist.org/search/cto?s={page}&auto_title_status=1&max_auto_miles=50000&nearbyArea=125&nearbyArea=20&nearbyArea=219&nearbyArea=237&nearbyArea=238&nearbyArea=330&nearbyArea=331&nearbyArea=332&nearbyArea=333&nearbyArea=37&nearbyArea=376&nearbyArea=557&nearbyArea=638&nearbyArea=639&nearbyArea=80&searchNearby=2'

craigs_list = []
for page in range(2):       # <-- increase the number of desired pages

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL.format(page=page*120)).content, 'html.parser')
    car_elems = soup.select('.rows li.result-row')

    for car_elem in car_elems:
        craigs_item = {
            'title': car_elem.find('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk').text,
            'price': car_elem.find('span', class_='result-price').text,
            'link': car_elem.a['href']
        }
        
        print(craigs_item['link'])
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(craigs_item['link']).content, 'html.parser')

        desc = soup.select_one('#postingbody')
        # sometimes, the posting is deleted. If yes, skip it.
        if not desc:
            continue
        desc.select_one('.print-information').extract()
        craigs_item['desc'] = desc.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n')

        for a in soup.select('.attrgroup')[-1].select('span'):
            k = a.find(text=True)
            v = k.find_next(text=True)
            if k.strip():
                craigs_item[k.split(':')[0]] = v

        craigs_list.append(craigs_item)
    
craigsList_df = pd.DataFrame(craigs_list)
print(craigsList_df)
craigsList_df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you! When I try to add the s=120 component to the URL or any kind of pagination to iterate through result pages, this code breaks. Any ideas on pagination for complete results?